# Looking for software to sync meeting time based on timezone

Tags: time-zone

I'm planning to set up a meeting on IRC with several people to discuss ideas for a game they're making.

Sad thing is, most of them are in different timezones and only available at certain hours.

What I'm looking for is a piece of software that I can use to enter all their timezones and the times they're available at, to determine the best possible moment for them all come online.

That's a pretty long description. I don't know if anything like it exists and my googles have turned up nothing. I'm probably not describing it good enough for google to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty standard feature for most calendar software.

Try Chandler or Google Calendar (there is even a lab extensions for auto scheduling such meetings).